# How to transform acceleration data to velocity data

Tags: imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My IMU( Xsens MTi-28A53G35) only puts out orientation, angular velocity and linear acceleration. I want to use this data to help improve the accuracy of odom of the robot.

The Robot_localization doesn't support acceleration data from IMU so I have to transform acceleration into velocity first. I am wondering whether there are any nodes that can do this or I have write a node for it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193018/how-to-transform-acceleration-data-to-velocity-data/) by [smartkian88@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/20237/smartkian88@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why don't you just ignore linear acceleration? Check [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials/Sensor%20Configuration). In the config param of your `imu` in the launch file, you can set the variables related to orientation and angular velocity as true and the rest as false. So your config param for `imu` should look like this:

```
<rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false, 
                                     true,  true,  true, 
                                     false, false, false, 
                                     true,  true,  true]</rosparam>
```

---

Originally posted by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) with karma: 651 on 2014-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually if you want to integrate different types of data like GPS, Odometry, Acceleration, Rotation, ect. to correct your actual position you will use a so called EKF (extended kalman filter). You will find a ready to use ros node to do this http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf  or you have to this be yourself in special cases!

---

Originally posted by [zumili](https://answers.ros.org/users/3935/zumili/) with karma: 141 on 2014-09-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2